# Using strtok() to tokenize strings (possibly multiple words) between integers, all separated by spaces

Tags: c, string, strtok

The format of the last line as seen below completely random. The first part of the program has experiment names inputted into *experiments[20] while data for each experiment is put into data[10][20]. After a certain line in the input redirection where `"*** END ***"` is read, the data input is terminated. The following line is of our options.They do this:1. Show all data. 2. Calculate the average for a specific experiment (therefore the name of the experiment HAS to follow `2` in the file. 3. Calculate the total average of all experiments. 4. End the program. Everything needs to be done through file redirection input

Main Question: How do i tokenize a string composed of two words, as you can see two lines below?

Ok, so we have stdin file redirection input of this last line of a file:

`1 2 Control Group 3 4`

There are 4 possible options: 1,2,3,4
2 is always followed by the name of an experiment as it calculates the average of that specific experiment.

We tokenize the line obtained through fgets() by doing this:
`token = strtok(str," ");`

and then by continuing like this for other integers:
`token = strtok(NULL," ");`

Each token of a number is scanned into an `int var` as such:
`sscanf (token, "%d", &var);`

When var is equal to 2, the switch statement creates a new token, expecting a String to follow. Originally I had written the code as such:
`printf("What experiment would you like to use?\n");
token = strtok (NULL," ");
sscanf (token, "%s", &str);`

And then I would compare `str` with my different experiment names in a loop using `strcmp`. However I only tested it with 1 word experiment names. Now I'm realizing the problem can be written as listed at the beginning of my question.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Thanks.

Comment: (i) extract the sign bits and determine the sign of the result, (ii) make both operands positive, (iii) do unsigned division, (iv) negate result if needed.

Comment: (i) So determine the numbers in base 10 and the expected sign of the result, (ii) if sign of either number is negative then turn that number into it's positive equivalent, (iii) do division with positive numbers which is pretty obvious considering you can immediately see which binary number is larger. So there is NO advantage to doing division with negative numbers - It seems like it will actually slow me down a ton. Correct?

Comment: No, you don't need to work with base 10 at all - just take the two input numbers, test the sign bits (MS bits), make both numbers positive, do the unsigned division, then fix the sign of the result if necessary. The unsigned division will still be the most expensive part - the sign handling is trivial.

Comment: Yeah after entering my comment I wondered why I wrote that first part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you have a mixture of strings and numbers, but an otherwise well formed input, would it make more sense to use `sscanf` after the initial `fgets()`? It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do, but this seems to me a case where `sscanf` has the better options. If you could describe more clearly what you want to achieve (for example, is the format always `number number word word number number` or does it depend on the value of `number`?) it should be easy to solve this. `strtok` seems an unnecessary intermediate step.

Comment: The format is completely random. The first part of the program has experiment names inputted into `*experiments[20]` while data for each experiment is put into `data[10][20]`. After a certain line in the input redirection where `"*** END ***"` is read, the data input is terminated. The following line is of our options.They do this:1. Show all data. 2. Calculate the average for a specific experiment (therefore the name of the experiment HAS to follow `2` in the file. 3. Calculate the total average of all experiments. 4. End the program. Everything needs to be done through file redirection input